# How to determine the identity of a UISlider assigned to a struct variable

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uislider

I have a struct that stores the last three `UISlider`s touched. These are defined in another class (my `ViewController`). 
Here's the struct:

```
struct lastSlider {
   var current: UISlider!
   var previous: UISlider!
   var previousprevious: UISlider!

   mutating func setCurrent(slider: UISlider) {
      if slider != current {
         //push into stack
         previousprevious = previous
         previous = current
         current = slider
   }
}
```

For debug purposes I want to be able to determine which UISliders are `lastSlider.current` etc. 
I have tried simply printing their `.debugDescription` but that only gives me information about them, not their name.

**How do I identify a `UISlider` for debugging?**

Comment: How about using tags? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag

Comment: Thats the answer! Wish you had made it an answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @crizzis wrote:

> How about using tags? developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag

This solved my problem!